# SQL Server: String Manipulation

Tags: sql-server, string, data-manipulation

I have currently managed to pull out a list of codes from some descriptions of which all should be formatted similarly for example:

> '%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%'
>   (00000-0000)
>   '%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%'
>   (0000-0000)
>   '%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9]%'
>   (00000-000)
>   '%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9]%'
>   (0000-000)
>   '%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]%'
>   (0000-00)

I have noticed the codes I have not currently pulled out as formatted as 00000000 and was wondering say if I were to pull these codes out if there was a way to restructure them to 00000-000?

The code I am currently using is as such based on the suggestion from Larnu yesterday if anybody could help with this String manipulation question would be greatly appreciated, If possible I would like to place the restructured string in the column with the others in the correct format.

```
WITH VTE AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM [Remedies].[dbo].[ShortageCompany] V)
SELECT  
       V.[ShortageDetailID]
      ,V.[ShortageID]
      ,V.[Company]
      ,V.[CompanyID]
      ,V.[Presentation]
      ,V.[Availability]
      ,V.[Information]
      ,V.[Reason]
      ,V.[StandardReason],

       CASE WHEN PI1.C > 0 THEN SUBSTRING(V.[Presentation],PI1.C, 10)
            WHEN PI2.C > 0 THEN SUBSTRING(V.[Presentation],PI2.C, 9)
            WHEN PI3.C > 0 THEN SUBSTRING(V.[Presentation],PI3.C, 9)
            WHEN PI4.C > 0 THEN SUBSTRING(V.[Presentation],PI3.C, 8)
            WHEN PI5.C > 0 THEN SUBSTRING(V.[Presentation],PI3.C, 7)


            ELSE NULL
       END AS N
FROM VTE V


     CROSS APPLY (VALUES(PATINDEX('%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%',V.[Presentation]))) PI1(C)
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES(PATINDEX('%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%',V.[Presentation]))) PI2(C)
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES(PATINDEX('%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9]%',V.[Presentation]))) PI3(C)
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES(PATINDEX('%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9]%',V.[Presentation]))) PI4(C)
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES(PATINDEX('%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]%',V.[Presentation]))) PI5(C)


ORDER BY [ShortageDetailID]
```

Comment: `STUFF('00000000', 6, 0, '-')` = `00000-000`.

Comment: For the OP's reference: [`STUFF` (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/stuff-transact-sql)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This method actually work, despite what I had said. The data I ran this query against was inconsistent and the code matched values where possible, although I had had to expand the search to look for a couple more varieties of Character structures.